# Get file data into a ByteArray using FileReference

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3

I am using the `FileReference` object. I want to be able to save the local file data into a `ByteArray`. I know that I can use the data property in Flash 10, but I would like a solution that works for earlier versions of Flash.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: And how do you suppose to get content of local file with flash?

Comment: in FLash 10 i can do it easily with Filereference. I wonder how i can do that with earlier flash versions

Answer (score 3):

You can't get access to file data in version of Flash Player before Flash 10.

I believe you should be able to use FileReference to upload the file to the server, and then send it back to the Flash Player as a byteArray.